# If UIKit is imported in the PCH file, then why is it imported again in each file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, precompiled-headers

If `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` and `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` are both found in our `ProjectName.pch' file, making them globally imported, why are they automatically added to the header file when Xcode creates a new class?

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> is automatically added to SubClass of UIView, #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> is automatically added to SubClass of NSObject, these are made ignore pch file. System will not check each import line in pch file which you add a new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .pch is there as a compile time optimisation, personally I recommend making sure that classes can still build without a pch (so still import into h/m's manually), so that it can A) build without and B) so that if you re-use code, you can easily see its dependencies.

> In general, newly-generated iOS projects come with this functionality, which is called a precompiled header or prefix header, and is a file that has the extension .pch.
>
> You can throw all the headers you want in there and Xcode will pre-compile it before it builds anything else, and use it to compile the other compilation units in your project (e.g. .m files).
>
> Using a precompiled header may or may not increase compile time; in general, it reduces compile time, as long as you have a lot of common headers and/or a lot of source files.
>
> However, it's not necessarily good practice to treat the pre-compiled header like a big dumping ground, as your compilation units can form implicit dependencies on all sorts of stuff when you may want to enforce loose coupling between components.

Comment: What do you mean by “the docs”? That seems to be from [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10910116/30461); I couldn't find it anywhere on Apple's site.

Answer (score 1):

Only Apple knows for sure.

Best guess: Apple can not be sure that the imports are in the pch file for all projects or that there is even a pch file. This by having these implicit imports compiling can be guaranteed.